# JMeter - Post Data passes JSON data

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, json

The Project which I am working now require a performance test. So, I preferred JMeter for a load test and started learning one by one.

Now, When I recorded a test and included a CSV file for the dynamic parameter. I see the recorded pages has client id in many HTTP POST data pages. This application passes a JSON data for sending a request so in Body Parameter tab I see JSON type data.

So,  added JSON Post Extractor for one HTTP request site passes alphanumeric value `(5963948e2f123bd00a27d5cd)`. However, after I executing the test the page returns an error page.

```
POST http://192.168.1.10/api/editClient/getClientInfo/

POST data: {"clientId":"5963948e2f123bd00a27d5cd"} 

Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request 
Response data: Failed to authenticate Token
```

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a header manager - try with Content-Type and if it didnt work then try with Accept; remember these for the future -
400 series error - Check the Header file
500 series error - check the data

Answer (score 1):

To get token values:: u need to pass parameters like username, password, grant_type, client_id n client_secret...which will be shared by respective developer of the API...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [application/json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

Another reason could be improper work of the JSON Extractor, double check the "token" variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.